# User Control vs. Rectangle/Alternatives

Tags: c#, performance, user-controls

I'm creating a program that is a tile based dungeon editor to develop games. The tiles that are shown on screen are user controls that are dynamically created once the user specifies the height and width of the level. These user controls are then added to a panel.

My main concern is the efficiency of what I'm doing. If a user creates a 20x20 level, will the amount of user controls "bog down" the program? Each control (or tile as it were) will hold an image and some other attributes such as collidable, interactive, etc.

Will I be okay using user controls, or is there a less expensive alternative out there for this sort of thing?

**EDIT:** Thanks for the initial replies! From what you guys have said, this won't be too expensive. However, what about the performance in terms of resizing these controls?

```
private void changeTileSizeOnScroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int newSize = sliderTileResizer.Value;

        for (int w = 0; w < matrixWidth; w++)
        {
            for (int h = 0; h < matrixHeight; h++)
            {
                pnlTileEditor.Controls[w * matrixHeight + h].Size = new Size(newSize, newSize);
                pnlTileEditor.Controls[w * matrixHeight + h].Location = new Point(newSize * w - w, newSize * h - h);                        
            }
        }
    }
```

I was going to use databinding for the trackbar and tiles, but I need to update the location based on the size of the tiles so that each tile is directly beside the previous one. Is this a terrible way to resize?

Comment: Is this a web forms app?

Comment: There is a less expensive alternative: draw on a single panel and when the user clicks the mouse on the panel, determine which tile he clicked on by doing some basic math on the mouse coordinates. But 400 controls shouldn't be a problem. It's not like they're all executing code at once.

Comment: Depends on the GUI class library you use, a UC is a complete window in Winforms but not in WPF.  An app with 400 windows will be sluggish.

Comment: Im WinForms you may be fine, but getting towards its limits. Maybe a DataGridView would help? Or go with Jim's suggestion! It depends on what is happening with those tiles, chess or more action..?

Comment: This isn't an app, it's a C# project.

Comment: @JimMischel This sounds really useful, but I'm worried about how tricky it may get down the road. I'm using mouse click and hover events for these tiles as well. The mouse click would be easy to check for each drawing, but would hover be feasible for drawings?

Comment: Sure, hover is easy enough. When you get the hover event, query `Cursor.Position` to get the mouse position, and then call `PointToClient` to get the mouse position relative to the control.

Comment: Okay, you've convinced me! I'm going to switch over from user controls to drawing rectangles. It's already seeming easier in my head to handle my code this way. Now here's a noob question: How do I mark this as answered seeing as there's only comments? Jim would get the credit for this one if it's possible.